# Reading in a text file c++

Tags: c++, file, opengl, fseek

While following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOzQ8jSOnbo in developing a 3d game using opengl and c++ I'm getting an error in the fseek:

```
char* ShaderInterface::loadTextFromFile(const char* file)
{
    FILE *currentFile = fopen(file, "rt");
    fseek(currentFile, 0, SEEK_END); // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    int count = (int)ftell(currentFile);
    // ...
}
```

I'm sure this should work as the source code in the git account does work, though i'm sure there's probably better ways to do this.

Comment: Error opening the file, maybe. Add a check. `if (currentFile == NULL)` and add error handling code.

Comment: This is more of a *story* than a *question* really.  You said "do this with a file"... and your OS said "No."

Answer (score 3):

When you call `fopen()`, you have to check the return value. That function can fail (if, for instance, the file doesn't exist):

```
FILE* currentFile = fopen(file, "rt");
if (currentFile) {
    // success
    fseek(currentFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    // etc.
}
else {
    // report error back about not being able to open file
    // check errno, maybe log perror(), etc...
}
```

Comment: This actually made me realise that it wasn't a matter of typos in my code – it was simply that my function couldn't find the file! :O Time to debug *that* issue…